# how do you convert a list to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have list as below and like to convert it to a data frame, any ideas?

x

str(x) looks like this:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 8
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "Home Page - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "Logon To My Accounts - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr " Check - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr " Activity - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "List - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "Recipient - User Time"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "Cancel - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : chr "2013-MAY-30 09:17 AM"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "Log Off - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "-"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 45693
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-05-30 09:17:00"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "-Online Home Page - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "4.145"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "100.00"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 42627
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-05-30 09:17:00"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "-Logon To My Accounts - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "6.185"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "100.00"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 42627
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-05-30 09:17:00"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "-Pay Bills - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "8.206"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "100.00"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 42627
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ DATE_TIME    : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-05-30 09:17:00"
  .. ..$ SITE         : chr "-Enter Payment Amounts - User Time]"
  .. ..$ RESPONSE_TIME: chr "4.976"
  .. ..$ AVAIL_PERCENT: chr "100.00"
  .. ..$ AGENT        : num 42627
```

Comment: It's better to use `str` and share the data (list) than to just post what it looks like.  This forces those helping to recreate your data.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker, post is updated with str.

Comment: My bad I meant to say `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a double nested list of data.frames, so try:

```
do.call(rbind,unlist(x,FALSE))
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Comment: I got it  row.names(yy) <- NULL

Comment: actually I just noticed that this is not really working. It works for some rows and then DATE_TIME column values are turning into epoch times rather than actual dates as the values in the list. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I noticed that some values are this format 2013-MAY-30 11:07 AM  and some are this 2013-05-30 11:07:00. The ones that has AM PM on them turning into epoch times.

Comment: It looks like they are different types in your list.